# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory issue after creating my own custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have created my own custom user profile model in django and when i tried to run  migrations & migrate command i'm coming up with an error
as

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration authtoken.0001_initial is applied before its dependency profiles_api.0001_initial on database 'default'
```

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email is required")
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(email=email,name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,name,password):
        """creates new super user with details """

        user=self.create_user(email,name,password)
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserProfiles(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects=UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD=['name']
    def get_fullname(self):
        return self.name
    def get_shortname(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.email
```

in setting i have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL='profiles_api.UserProfiles'`

and i have tried to remove my initial database like 000init.py files and check if this could work

any kind of help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Try deleting or flushing your database

Comment: done ,but it's of no use

Comment: Delete the migration **folders** of your apps and the db too, then `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes ,it worked but when i tried to run create super user popped up with an another error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: profiles_api_userprofiles
even after running makemigratiosn and migrate commands i dont know how to solve this issue

Comment: i have mentioned it in the previous comment

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError:no such table:profiles_api_userprofiles

Comment: Is your app `userprofiles` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`, if it is try `python manage.py makemigrations userprofiles` then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: my app name is profiles_api and it is added in my installed app section in my settings.py file and i tried running python manage.py makemigrations profiles_api and migrate commands but it's of no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When substituting the django `User` model, and you already made migrations to DB, you should consider start over by deleting the database (or at least the user table if the other table does not involve the user table at all and this is usually not the case) and also the migrations **folders**

`settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'profiles_api',
    ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL='profiles_api.UserProfiles'
```

in terminal:

some times `mikemigrations` does not detect changes and return

> makemigrations returns "No changes detected.

So it's helpful to specify the `app` name

```
> python manage.py makemigrations profiles_api
> python manage.py makemigrations
> python manage.py migrate
```

I hope this will help.